# How to include the django-allauth signup form on a page?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth and it's great. However, I'd like to create a splash page that has the signup form on it. What templatetag can I use to include the signup form in my template?

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide some information on what you've tried? Have you consulted the documentation? This question may get closed because of the lack of information.

Comment: I have consulted the documentation, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything that would help: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#templates

Comment: You can set `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` and create your own signup form.

Answer (score 0):

Check on http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#social-account-tags

You can show the social buttons with the **provider_login_url** tag.

```
{% load socialaccount %}

<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
<a href="{% provider_login_url "twitter" %}">Twitter</a>
```